# Want to write jasmine unit test cases for addEventListener in angularjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write jasmine unit test cases for code written in angularJS directive. Following is the code :

```
document.getElementById(scope.elementID).addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    $rootScope.isGoogleLocationProgress = true;
    //   destinationReady = true;
});
document.getElementById(scope.elementID).addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    $rootScope.isGoogleLocationProgress = true;
    //   destinationReady = false;
});
document.getElementById(scope.elementID).addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    $document.on('click', checkForClearClick);

    function checkForClearClick(e) {
        if (e.target) {
            if (e.target.name != "clearSearch") {
                $timeout(getLocationPrediction, 0);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please Help me to add it

Comment: StackOverflow isn't about writing code for you, it's about helping you with code you've written. Give it a try, read about how to test jasmine/angular if you need to and come back when you're having a problem with what you've written.  For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just give a name to the functions you use in the listeners, and unit test these functions.

That's it.

Example:

```
document.getElementById(scope.elementID).addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
                    $rootScope.isGoogleLocationProgress = true;
                 //   destinationReady = true;
                });
```

becomes

```
var yourFunc = function(e) {
    $rootScope.isGoogleLocationProgress = true;
    // destinationReady = true
};
document.getElementById(scope.elementID).addEventListener('focus', yourFunc);
```

Now you can unit test your function `myFunc`.

Comment: But In my case, I cannot edit angular code. Because it is already written by another member. I just I have to write unit test cases for existing code. Could you please share your opinion accordingly?

Comment: I'm affraid you can't unit test something you can't call.